# Операции с привязанными свойствами XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

Необходимо в `WrapPanel` добиться того чтобы высота и ширина внутренних элементов всегда была равна трети ширины содержащего его контейнера. Как привязывать "голые" свойства - понятно. Как выполнять над ними арифметические операции - не ясно.

Код XAML:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="scrMenu" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
            <WrapPanel 
                ItemHeight="{Binding ElementName=scrMenu,Path=ActualWidth}" 
                ItemWidth="{Binding ElementName=scrMenu,Path=ActualWidth}" 
                Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button Margin="5" Background="AliceBlue" Content="1" />
                <Button Margin="5" Background="Blue" Content="2" />
                <Button Margin="5" Background="Aquamarine" Content="3"/>
                <Button Margin="5" Background="DarkGreen" Content="4"/>
                <Button Margin="5" Background="LightGreen" Content="5"/>
                <Button Margin="5" Background="AliceBlue" Content="6"  />
                <Button Margin="5" Background="Blue" Content="7" />
            </WrapPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

Хотелось бы знать, можно ли как то так:

```
ItemHeight="{Binding ElementName=scrMenu,Path=ActualWidth/3}" 
ItemWidth="{Binding ElementName=scrMenu,Path=ActualWidth/3}"
```

Comment: Почему не использовать Grid вместо WrapPanel? Ну а вообще почитайте про конвертеры.

Comment: @АндрейNOP Пытался использовать конвертер, но компилятор орёт, что Имя "WidthConverter" не существует в пространстве имен "clr-namespace:stranbs" когда я его объявляю в <UserControl.Resources>. Как с этим справиться не пойму. Grid использовать не могу из за того что не знаю заранее о количестве элементов в контейнере.

Answer (score 0):

Пришлось очистить ShadowCache и пересобрать проект. Заработало с конвертером.

```
namespace stranbs
{
    public class WidthConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return ((double)value)/3;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return ((double)value) * 3;
        }
    }
}
```

Добавил ресурс:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <local:WidthConverter x:Key="mconc"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

Описал свойства:

```
ItemHeight="{Binding ElementName=scrMenu,Path=ActualWidth,Converter={StaticResource mconc}}" 
ItemWidth="{Binding ElementName=scrMenu,Path=ActualWidth,Converter={StaticResource mconc}}"
```